# where do I get the Jasmine framework function definitions for Protractor.

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Is there any possibility to get the support documents or guidelines to prepare the standard custom framework like Jasmine for protractor

Answer (score 0):

Does these help?

[Protractor in General](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/toc.md)

[Protractor APIs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api)